# EXCEL Time Field

Tags: excel

```
Time 13:15:09          Batch 09:00 to 18:00
```

I have to compare if Column1(Time) is between the time mentioned in Column2(Batch)

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished using `MEDIAN` function in Excel.

Try the following formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))=MEDIAN(RIGHT(A1,8),MID(B1,7,5),RIGHT(B1,5))
```

And to be on safer side you can use `TIMEVALUE` for all the values used in formula as:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))=MEDIAN(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8)),TIMEVALUE(MID(B1,7,5)),TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B1,5)))
```

Comment: interesting usage of Median.  I like it!  Very special case with only 3 values.  Its a nice chunk of formula to drop in an if statement if not content with simply TRUE/FALSE result.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Thank you! I've been using formula like this for sometime. Don't really remember where I saw this.

Comment: out of curiosity what happen if the number you are checking, is equal to one of the boundaries?  in this case the time in A1 was 09:00:00 or 18:00:00?

Comment: @ForwardEd - Its just a normal `MEDIAN` function. Mathematically, median of 1,2,3 is 2 and median of 1,1,3 is  1. So what you are asking is the second case where numbers are 1,1,3. And if the number is same as the upper boundary then it will median of 1,3,3 which is 3. So it will still give `TRUE` if the number matches either of the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

we will assume your data is all in a string and the format of the string does not change.  We will pull out the time through some string manipulations and counting and use the timevalue function in the end.

Let assume for now that we are pulling the column A time out and placing it in column B.  This is a temporary step and will disappear when all combined in one cell at the end.  Since we know the time is the last 8 characters we can use the following:

```
=Timevalue(Right(A1,8))
```

Now let pull the first time in column B.  Lets us a left right string strip combination to pull the time.  We could also use mid.  The first formula would look like:

```
=timevalue(right(left(B1,11),5))

or

=timevalue(MID(B1,7,5))
```

To pull out the second time the easiest approach would be a reapeat of what we did for the first time we pulled out and use the RIGHT formula:

```
=timevalue(right(B1,5))
```

Now you could put all those in separate columns to ensure they are working and assist you will building your final equation.  With all that in one cell, you final equation would look something like.

```
=if(AND(Timevalue(Right(A1,8))<=timevalue(right(B1,5)),Timevalue(Right(A1,8))>=timevalue(MID(B1,7,5))),"Time is within batch time","Time outside batchtime")
```